# How to add indicator based on Python DataFrame dataset using an attribute and add as a separate column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataset defined as below

```
ADDRESS CITY    STATE   ZIP LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT  06066 4701  43
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT  06066 47    41
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT  06066 470   42
```

I need to add an indicator column which checks if the `LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES` is maximum, then set it as 1 else 0. For the example the `LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES` 43 should be having corresponding indicator as 1 and other rows having indicator values as 0.

I need to do it using Pandas only.

Expected output:

```
ADDRESS CITY    STATE   ZIP LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES  INDICATOR
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT  06066 4701  43  1
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT  06066 47    41  0
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT  06066 470   42  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comapre values by maximum and convert boolean mask to `0,1`:

```
df['INDICATOR'] = df.LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.eq(df.LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.max()).astype(int)

df['INDICATOR'] = df.LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.eq(df.LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.max()).view('i1')

df['INDICATOR'] = np.where(df.LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.eq(df.LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.max()), 1, 0)
```